# kuberetes hostPort declaration not working for pods in StatefulSet, any extra config needed?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am deploying the helm chart [mongodb-replicaset](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb-replicaset). I have added the hostPort 27017 in the StatefulSet containers spec. However, the port is not being exposed. It is silently ignoring this. If I deploy a pod spec with hostPort in the same kube, it works. Is there something incompatible in the StatefulSet for this, or am I missing some configuration? My use case is I need the db to be externally accessible. Given how mongo works, load balancing makes no sense here, hostPort being the most direct path. Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no additional settings for `StatefulSet` required for `NodePort`.

But, your `NodePort` value should be in the available range (default: 30000-32767).

The simplest way to fix it is to set `NodePort` value to one of the ports from the available range.

Comment: I have looked at the NodePort service option, but do no want to move the port from the standard 27017. So I have been working on using hostPort to solve this. Also from what I am seeing, setting a NodePort service puts a load balancing behavior to the service...

Comment: No, load balancing is an independent thing and more related to Service. You have 2 options here to run `NodePort: 27017` - run your pods with `hostNetwork: true`, or extend the range of available ports for services by `--service-node-port-range=` Kubelet flag.